# Add styling to HTTP Basic Authentication prompt

Tags: html, css

Hi i have a website that i use a .htpasswd thing on to protect my directory but is there a way to make this look better?

https://prnt.sc/r3Dk5iUMOZKw

Answer (score 2):

No, this is a native browser component that you cannot modify. You can build your own password protected page to access your directory but it is a whole another story.